# AdMob Mediation: iAds Not Displaying Correctly on iOS 6

Tags: ios, ios6, admob, iad

I'm using AdMob's mediation to display adds in my iPhone App.

On all versions of iOS 5, both AdMob ads and iAds display correctly at all times.

On iOS 6, AdMob ads still display correctly at all times, but below, you will see the issue I am having with iAds.  Again, this is only on iOS 6.  The iAd displays behind the NavBar and gets blocked/chopped off by the tab bar.

Here is the code I am using to setup my `GADBannerView`:

```
    GADBannerView *tempBannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];
    self.bannerView = tempBannerView;

    bannerView.adUnitID = @"OUR_ID_HERE";  //Our Mediation ID
    bannerView.rootViewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController;
    bannerView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:bannerView];

    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    request.testing = NO;
    [bannerView loadRequest:request];
```

**Before Tapping Ad**

[image: Before]

**After Tapping**

[image: After]

Comment: How are you adding your navBar in this case? Do you have a navBar in your hierarchy, or are you creating a UINavigationController inside your UITabBarController?

Comment: What UIViewController is your window's rootViewController?

Comment: Unless something was released in the past 48 hours, I was using the most recent version of the SDK and the most recent version of the iAd adapter (not sure what version numbers those are).  My Navigation Controller is setup inside the ViewController that is being presented by the favorites tab.

Comment: My UITabBarController is my window's rootViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I did not find a solution, I decided to see if this is "my problem" or not.  I replaced my GADViewBanner with Apple's ADViewBanner and tried implementing just iAd myself and abandoning AdMob mediation.

After implementing the right delegates, the AdViewBanner displays correctly at all times!  In other words... I blame something wonky with the mediation software.

If anybody has any fixes to the original issue, feel free to post.  Otherwise, I will just be using iAds implemented myself instead of trying to use AdMob mediation.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fix this exact problem for 2 days now. I agree that this is a problem with AdWhirl, as the Google AdMob ads work just fine.

Although I never found a "proper" solution, I did devise the following work-around. There are some AdWhirl events which games can use to pause the game when the user clicks an ad, and I hooked into these to hide all the appropriate assets while the ad is being displayed (an. Although AdWhirl should do this, for some reason in my case it doesn't, and unlike the person who posted the question I want to use ad mediation, so the workaround is the best solution for me.

```
- (void)adWhirlWillPresentFullScreenModal {
    [((MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).navController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    [SwitchViewController.instance.toolbar setHidden:YES];  // SwitchViewController is actually the root view controller also. It contains a custom toolbar.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
}
- (void)adWhirlDidDismissFullScreenModal {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
    [((MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).navController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
    [SwitchViewController.instance.toolbar setHidden:NO];
}
```